# MYSQL group and count by start, end times

Tags: mysql, database

I'd like to take a database that looks like this:

```
| Start      | End         |
|------------|-------------|
| 15:00:00   |    18:00:00 |
| 15:00:00   |    19:00:00 |
| 15:00:00   |    18:00:00 |
| 16:00:00   |    19:00:00 |
| 17:00:00   |    21:00:00 |
| 17:00:00   |    21:00:00 |
```

and get a query that returns this

```
| Start      | End         | Count |
|------------|-------------|-------|
| 15:00:00   |    18:00:00 |   2   |
| 15:00:00   |    19:00:00 |   1   |
| 16:00:00   |    19:00:00 |   1   |
| 17:00:00   |    21:00:00 |   2   |
```

Any suggestions? How can I group by both start and end time, and then count them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Select `Start`, `End`, Count(*) as ct FROM table GROUP BY `Start`,`End`
```

Should do the trick?

Comment: perfect! way easier than I thought. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

Use this query

```
SELECT Start, End, COUNT(*) FROM TableName GROUP BY Start, End
```